# Tangent line to a hyperbola

Tags: calculus

Can anyone explain and prove the following statement?

Any tangent line to a hyperbola touches the hyperbola halfway between the points of intersection of the tangent and the asymptotes.

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derivating implicity the equation of the canonical hyperbola:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1\Longrightarrow \frac{2x}{a^2}dx-\frac{2y}{b^2}dy=0\Longrightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{b^2x}{a^2y}$$

Thus, at any point $\,(x_1,y_1)\,$ on the hyperbola, the tangent line is

$$\text{I}\;\;\;y-y_1=\frac{b^2x_1}{a^2y_1}(x-x_1)\Longleftrightarrow y=\frac{b^2x_1}{a^2y_1}x-\frac{b^2}{y_1}$$

The hyperbola's asymptotes are the lines

$$\text{II}\;\;\;\;y=\pm\frac{b}{a}x$$

The intersection points between I and II are

$$\frac{b^2x_1}{a^2y_1}x-\frac{b^2}{y_1}=\pm\frac{b}{a}x\Longrightarrow\left(\frac{b^2x_1}{a^2y_1}\mp\frac{b}{a}\right)x=\frac{b^2}{y_1}\Longrightarrow$$

$$x=\frac{a^2b}{bx_1\mp ay_1}\Longrightarrow y=\pm\frac{ab^2}{bx_1\mp ay_1}$$

so the points are

$$A=\left(\frac{a^2b}{bx_1-ay_1}\;,\;\frac{ab^2}{bx_1-ay_1}\right)\;\;,\;\;B=\left(\frac{a^2b}{bx_1+ay_1}\;,\;-\frac{ab^2}{bx_1+ay_1}\right)$$

The midpoint of $\,AB\,$ is

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\left[\frac{a^2b}{bx_1-ay_1}+\frac{a^2b}{bx_1+ay_1}\right]\;,\;\left[\frac{ab^2}{bx_1-ay_1}-\frac{ab^2}{bx_1+ay_1}\right]\right)=$$

$$\frac{1}{2}(2x_1\,,\,2y_1)=(x_1,y_1)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\square$$

**Note:** Be sure you can prove all the steps above, and **remember**: $\,(x_1,y_1)\,$ is a point *on the hyperbola*!

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!!

Answer (score 2):

WLOG, we can assume the equation of the hyperbola to be $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

Any point on this hyperbola can be parametrized as P$(a\sec\theta,b\tan\theta)$

According to the Article#$305$ of [The elements of coordinate geometry(Loney)](http://archive.org/download/elementsofcoordi00loneuoft/elementsofcoordi00loneuoft.pdf), the equation of the tangent is  $$\frac{x a\sec\theta}{a^2}-\frac{yb\tan\theta}{b^2}=1\implies bx-ay\sin\theta=ab\cos\theta--->(1)$$

According to the Article#$313$ of the same book, the equation of the [asymptotes](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/hyperbola.htm) are $$y=\pm\frac{bx}a--->(2)$$

Now, solve the two equations and find the intersection to prove the proposition.